# Xcode project — old files warnings

Tags: xcode, warnings

I have a lot of warnings in my Xcode project about old files that have been deleted from my project and from the project's folder.

I have tried to delete the "build" folder of the project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sort of warnings are you seeing?

In Xcode go to the Build menu and select Clean, then try to build again. Sometimes deleting the build folder is not enough.

If you explore the project do you see any file names that are red? If so, click to select them and press Delete.

Comment: Thank you for replying,
I tried to clean but I still get the errors.
I don't see red files in my Xcode project

Comment: Could you post an example of the warnings that you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Are you, by chance, using this project from a source code repository?

You need to remove the files from the repository as well.  For instance, "svn delete ".